# Dynamically POST php variables

Tags: php, variables, post, dynamic

Attempting to POST a certain number of variables based on the number of images in a folder. The variables are based on numbers found in fields with input name "Pano__000nheading" when n is the number in the current loop. I believe i have the code working properly on the page which is getting the values just need help if you see any flaws here  is my code:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
 $id = substr( $url, strrpos( $url, '&' )+1 );
    $dirname = "../wp-content/themes/Explorable/".$id."/"; 
  $images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents  
foreach($images as $image) {
 $imageNameLong = substr($image, -14);
$imageName = substr($imageNameLong,0 , -4);

 if ( isset( $_POST[$imageName.'links'] ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_'.$imageName.'links', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$imageName.'links'] ) );
        else
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_'.$imageName.'links' ); 

    if ( isset( $_POST[$imageName.'heading'] ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_'.$imageName.'heading', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$imageName.'heading'] ) );
        else
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_'.$imageName.'heading' ); 
};
```

Comment: Flaw #0: You're using individual variables rather than arrays.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking for help on - there are certainly improvements you can like using arrays, filtering the $_SERVER vars, etc.

Comment: thanks for the comments guys! I'm a relative noob to php so please bare with me on some things such as arrays. I'm trying to pass these variables to another page I feel as if my code should be WORKING not saying its the most efficient. I would love any help figuring this out! and if you have time a brief iteration of what my code would look like as an array? :) Thanks!

Comment: @GO3DExpansion: We didn't once mention efficiency.  My point is, you're making a lot of work for yourself the way things are named.  It's a common noob mistake.  But you're dealing with a bunch of related data; were the fields named something like `"images[{$i}][links]"`, they would basically organize themselves into a tree of data.  You could just loop through the resulting array, rather than all this farting around with rebuilding field names and searching for them.  (The image names, by the way, probably ought to be values rather than keys. PHP likes mangling top-level form variable names.)